# Hiera, default site.pp and error could not find class

Tags: puppet, server, system-administration, hiera

I have a server who was running puppet and hiera and, for the moment, 1 client.
I want to manage all my nodes with hiera config files so I only put this in /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp :

```
hiera_include(classes, '')
```

In my file /etc/puppet/hieradata/common :

```
---
classes:
  - "common_test"
  - fw_test
  - zabbix::agent

    zabbix::agent:zabbix_version : '2.2'
    zabbix::agent:server: 192.168.1.1
    zabbix::agent:serveractive: '192.168.1.1'
    zabbix::agent:hostname: 'Test_puppet'
    zabbix::agent:manage_firewall: true
```

With this configuration my parameters (192.168.1.1, true, Test_puppet, etc.) are not set on my client.

Second question, when I add `zabbix::userparameters` in my class list I have this error `Could not find class zabbix::userparameters for...`
But this class exist (I use this package https://forge.puppetlabs.com/wdijkerman/zabbix)

I take this example but it's also does'nt work with others classes for the parameters error.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter keys are incorrect.  For example, this ...

> zabbix::agent:zabbix_version : '2.2'

... should instead be ...

> zabbix::agent::zabbix_version: '2.2'

.  The main issue is one too few colons between `zabbix::agent` and `zabbix_version`.  I don't *think* whitespace between the key and trailing colon matters, but it's more conventional to not have any.

As for `zabbix::userparameters`, it is a (defined) resource type, not a class.  You cannot `include` it (or `hiera_include()` it).

Comment: Oh it's really simple, thank you very much !
Have you an idea for userparameters ?
Can i do something like that zabbix::agent::userparameters:source: '...' ?

Comment: You can create your own class to wrap a declaration of a `zabbix::userparameters`.  You can give that class whatever parameters it needs, and declare it and its parameters via hiera.  Note, however, that the point of `zabbix::userparameters` being a resource type instead of a class should be to enable nodes to declare more than one.  Thus, although the strategy I describe should work from a Puppet perspective, I cannot speak to whether it is actually the right thing to do for your nodes.

Comment: Ok i gonna try that tomorrow. I have a last question. I have write a puppet module (not publish). His init.p begin like `class testasterisk($host_patton = undef, ...`. But when i set parameter in my hiera file with `testasterisk::host_patton: '192.168.1.1'` it doesn't seems to work. I use host_patton variable in a template with `<%= @host_patton %>` and it's perfectly work when I only use puppet. Have you an idea ? Thank you very much for your precious help =)

Comment: Your description of your module layout, hiera data, and template appear correct.  If the data are in fact in a file that Hiera will consult for the node in question, and if there is no higher-priority data file in the picture, then I have to conclude that your description is mistaken.  Possibly the data file contains a typo in the `tecfaxbox::host_patton` key.  Alternatively, if there is also a `tecfaxbox::texfaxbox` class then under certain circumstances you might be confused about which one you are actually declaring.

Comment: regarding `zabbix::agent::userparameters:source:`, it should be `zabbix::userparameters::source:`

Comment: @BMW, No.  `zabbix::userparameters` is a defined type, not a class.  You cannot (automatically) bind parameter values to it via hiera.  You can *manually* call hiera to get values for its parameters, but in that case the keys can be anything.